# How to make a hair look normal or not blocky

Tags: modeling, texturing, transparency, hair

[image]

So...hello, i'm new in both blender (started using blender 2 weeks ago) and this forum, and currently i'm trying to edit/posing a 3D model from any game

I've succeeded in a few renders, but now i want to try something new
Currently, i'm trying to add textures and getting the model ready, but there's something that i don't know how to do

As you can see, this is the model that i'm preparing to pose, but the hair seems kinda blocky and not a normal smooth hair. I read in the comment section of that model and the creator told a person it has to do with alpha mapping?  Can any of you please help me? Thanks in advance.

The model: https://www.deviantart.com/crazy31139/art/Final-Fantasy-7-Remake-Cloud-833037551

How it should look: [image]

Comment: Are your textures connected through nodes?

Comment: Yes, i connected the textures from image textures to base color in nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an image of how I connected the maps for just the hair. I'm sure you figured out by now (It took me a minute) that the suffix letter to the map name refers to what kind of map it is (Ex: M = Metallic, N = Normal, C = Color, and A = Alpha). What threw me for a second is that unlike common setups which have the alpha as a built-in component of the basecolor map, this one uses a separate map, using the color, not the alpha value. See below:

[image: CloudHairAlpha]

Also - note the blend modes I highlighted on the right side. You can play with them to your liking, just don't pick opaque - that will leave things opaque and "blocky" as you said.

NOTE -  I just noticed, in the image I provided, the metallic map is set to sRGB color space, this should be non-color.

Hope this helps

Comment: Please provide additional important information relevant to your answer as an edit, not as a comment.  There are a great many users that ignore comments entirely.Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Christopher Bennet  for your help.Hope you have a great day.

Comment: @Wall-yee don't forget to give Christopher credit by checking the solution as ACCEPTED.  It will also hope steer other users to this Q&A when they see it marked as such.